# Detect elapsed time between two conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, time, react-redux

I'm curently working on a React app and trying to detect the time taken to reach a certain input value length.

It is a controlled input which value is stored and set via redux action and reducer.

I want to start counting time when the input value is `!== ""` and stop counting when the value `.length` is equal to 13.

Further, in the app logic, if the time taken to reach `.length === 13` is something like under `100ms` ( + or - ) it will mean that the app user used a barcode scanner, else, he typed the barcode with the keyboard.

i've tried to use vars with `new Date()` to get the time diff but the `render()` logic blocks the maintain of the elapsed time count...

Any idea of how i could achieve my goal ?

I leave you the component code just below, 
Thank you in advance !

```
import React from "react";
import StoreInput from "../StoreInput/index";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./index.scss";

import { setStoreInputFieldValue } from "../../actions/store.actions";
import { addArticleToStore } from "../../actions/articles.actions";

type ScanSetProps = {
  // Redux State
  storeInputFieldValue?: any;

  // Redux Actions
  setStoreInputFieldValue?: any;
  addArticleToStore?: any;
};

class ScanSet extends React.Component<ScanSetProps> {
  handleScanSet = (event) => {
    const { setStoreInputFieldValue } = this.props;
    setStoreInputFieldValue(event.target.value);
  };

  // Component render
  render() {
    const { storeInputFieldValue, addArticleToStore } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="ScanSet">
        <StoreInput
          idStoreInput={"scanSetInput"}
          typeStoreInput={"number"}
          placeholderStoreInput={
            "Scannez le code barre ou saisissez le code EAN"
          }
          storeInputFillMethod={this.handleScanSet}
        />
        <button
          id="scanSetButton"
          className={
            storeInputFieldValue.length === 13
              ? "enabledButton"
              : "disabledButton"
          }
          onClick={() => addArticleToStore(storeInputFieldValue)}
        >
          Ajouter
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  storeInputFieldValue: state.store.storeInputFieldValue,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setStoreInputFieldValue: (input_value) =>
    dispatch(setStoreInputFieldValue(input_value)),
  addArticleToStore: (article_ean) => dispatch(addArticleToStore(article_ean)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScanSet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using state.

When input !== "":

```
this.setState((state) => {...state, startTime: new Date().getTime()});
```

When value.length === 13:

```
this.setState((state) => {...state, endTime: new Date().getTime()});
```

Then you can have another part that accounts for the difference **(endTime - startTime)**

Since you're using `redux` if you have a slice that accounts for this. You can simply dispatch the two actions `setStartTime, setEndTime` and let the reducer handle the logic above.

Comment: Well nice idea ! I'll try this and let you know, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Urmzd's answer was a good approach, it solved my problem and also used the Redux Saga library each time a `"SET_END_TIME"` action is triggered to `getTimeDiff` and launch the further logic. Here is what code now looks like :

1. **Component Code : index.tsx**

```
import StoreInput from "../StoreInput/index";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./index.scss";

import {
  setStoreInputFieldValue,
  setStartTime,
  setEndTime,
  resetTimeDiff,
} from "../../actions/store.actions";
import { handleInputEan } from "../../actions/articles.actions";

type ScanSetProps = {
  // Redux State
  storeInputFieldValue?: any;

  // Redux Actions
  setStoreInputFieldValue?: any;
  handleInputEan?: any;
  setStartTime?: any;
  setEndTime?: any;
  resetTimeDiff?: any;
};

class ScanSet extends React.Component<ScanSetProps> {
  handleScanSet = (event) => {
    const {
      setStoreInputFieldValue,
      storeInputFieldValue,
      setStartTime,
      setEndTime,
      resetTimeDiff,
    } = this.props;
    setStoreInputFieldValue(event.target.value);
    if (storeInputFieldValue.length + 1 === 1) {
      setStartTime();
    } else if (storeInputFieldValue.length + 1 === 13) {
      setEndTime();
    } else if (storeInputFieldValue.length - 13 === 0) {
      resetTimeDiff();
    }
  };

  // Component render
  render() {
    const { storeInputFieldValue, handleInputEan } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="ScanSet">
        <StoreInput
          idStoreInput={"scanSetInput"}
          typeStoreInput={"number"}
          placeholderStoreInput={
            "Scannez le code barre ou saisissez le code EAN"
          }
          storeInputFillMethod={this.handleScanSet}
        />

        <button
          id="scanSetButton"
          className={
            storeInputFieldValue.length === 13
              ? "enabledButton"
              : "disabledButton"
          }
          onClick={() => handleInputEan()}
        >
          Ajouter
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  storeInputFieldValue: state.store.storeInputFieldValue,
  timeDiff: state.store.timeDiff,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setStartTime: () => dispatch(setStartTime()),
  setEndTime: () => dispatch(setEndTime()),
  resetTimeDiff: () => dispatch(resetTimeDiff()),
  setStoreInputFieldValue: (input_value) =>
    dispatch(setStoreInputFieldValue(input_value)),
  handleInputEan: () => dispatch(handleInputEan()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScanSet);
```

2. **Actions Code : store.actions.js ( with consts from store.const.js )**

```
import * as storeConst from "../const/store.const";

export const setStartTime = () => ({
  type: storeConst.SET_START_TIME,
  payload: new Date().getTime(),
});

export const setEndTime = () => ({
  type: storeConst.SET_END_TIME,
  payload: new Date().getTime(),
});

export const getTimeDiff = () => ({
  type: storeConst.GET_TIME_DIFF,
});

export const resetTimeDiff = () => ({
  type: storeConst.RESET_TIME_DIFF,
});
```

3. **Reducers Code : store.reducer.js ( with consts from store.const.js and reducers combined in an index.js file)**

```
import * as storeConst from "../const/store.const";

const initState = {
  startTime: null,
  endTime: null,
  timeDiff: null,
};

const store = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case storeConst.SET_START_TIME:
      return { ...state, startTime: action.payload };

    case storeConst.SET_END_TIME:
      return { ...state, endTime: action.payload };

    case storeConst.GET_TIME_DIFF:
      return { ...state, timeDiff: state.endTime - state.startTime };

    case storeConst.RESET_TIME_DIFF:
      return { ...state, timeDiff: null };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default store;
```

4. **Redux Saga Code : store.saga.js ( combined: in an index.js file as rootSaga)**

```
import { put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { store } from "../store";
import {
  getTimeDiff,
  resetTimeDiff,
} from "../actions/store.actions";
import {
  handleInputEan,
} from "../actions/articles.actions";

export function* getTimeDiffLogic() {
  yield put(getTimeDiff());
  const timeDiff = yield store.getState().store.timeDiff;
  if (timeDiff < 250) {
    yield put(handleInputEan());
    yield put(resetTimeDiff());
  }
}
```

Hope that will help someone like it helped me a lot !